# CSS - image position problems

Tags: html, css

```css
html body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
hr{
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000066;
}
.navbar li {
    float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #848dff;
}

.active {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.navbar{
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    position: center;
    height: 51px;
}

.prof{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.prof h1{
    font-family: "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center!important;
    font-style: none;
}
.prof p{
    font-family: "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
    text-align:center!important;
    font-style: none;
}
.center{
    width: 106px;
    height: 106px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: none;
   position: middle;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sort{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 115px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #4c4cff;
}
.sort ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.sort li a {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sort li a:hover {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<head>
 <title>AUXILIUM</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.php" alt="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" alt="Profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" alt="Students"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" alt="Schedules"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
<div class="prof">
<h1>My Profile</h1>
<p class="center">
 <img src="avatar3.png" class="center">
</p>
<hr>
<p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o">Professor Name</i></p>
<p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o">Professor ID</i></p>
<p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o">Department</i></p>
</div>
<div class="sort">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Year</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Course</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

hi beginner here need help in my current project(it is still on-going i started it a minute ago) the image i need to can be placed in the position i needed it to be and when i add new tags it keeps moving away please help and thank you.

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<head>
    <title>AUXILIUM</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.php" alt="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" alt="Profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" alt="Students"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" alt="Schedules"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
<div class="prof">
<h1>My Profile</h1>
<p class="center">
    <img src="avatar3.png" class="center">
</p>
<hr>
<p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o">Professor Name</i></p>
<p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o">Professor ID</i></p>
<p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o">Department</i></p>
</div>
<div class="sort">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Year</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Course</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
 html body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
hr{
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000066;
}
.navbar li {
    float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #848dff;
}

.active {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.navbar{
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    position: center;
    height: 51px;
}

.prof{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.prof h1{
    font-family: "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center!important;
    font-style: none;
}
.prof p{
    font-family: "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
    text-align:center!important;
    font-style: none;
}
.center{
    width: 106px;
    height: 106px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: none;
   position: middle;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sort{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 115px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #4c4cff;
}
.sort ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.sort li a {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sort li a:hover {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

as you can see it is a beginners that is why the codes are few and the designs is still very plain.

Comment: What image, and where did you want that image?

Comment: Please provide working snippet code and which image can't place its position?

Comment: the avatar3.png it should be at the center of its div but it wont go at the center

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the center class to this:

```
.center{
    width: 106px;
    height: 106px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: none;
    margin: 5px auto 10px auto;
}
```

By setting the left and right margins to `auto` it centers automatically.